# how to scroll image automatically on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

I have div tag with fix height and width and into that div i have image which is bigger in height and width than parent div. div has property **overflow:scroll**.
now i want to select some area of image and when i reach at max width and height and selection go out of that need to scroll automatically. image not scrolls automatically.
i am using jcrop plugin.

```
$("#img").Jcrop({
    allowMove: true,
    allowResize: true,
    allowSelect: true,
    onSelect: updateCropCoords
});
```

how to scroll image automatically on selection?

Comment: What happens in the div when you do not use JCrop?